# php mysql echo value with highest counter in table

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

I have a mySQL table PRERENDER like this

```
id | canonical     | prerender      | count
------------------------------------------------
01 | example.com/1 | Example.com/23 | 12

02 | example.com/1 | Example.com/54 | 10

03 | example.com/2 | Example.com/5  | 12
...
```

canonical + prerender are an index, the couple can't be duplicated. if the couple already exists so add +1 to count

What I need:

I need to get

when active URL = $canonical get the prerender field with the highest counter.

this is what I try:

```
 $canonical="https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
 $sql2 = mysql_query('
 SELECT prerender 
 FROM PRERENDER 
 WHERE (canonical = '.$canonical.') AND (count = MAX(count))
 ';
```

Any tips?

CODE UPDATE

```
$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";
$referral=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$referral = strtok($referral, '?');
$canonical="https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if ((strpos($referral, 'evemilano.com') !== false)) {
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO PRERENDER (ID,canonical,prerender,count) VALUES (NULL,'$referral','$canonical','1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count +1         ";
}
if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));}

$sql2 = "SELECT prerender FROM PRERENDER WHERE canonical = '$canonical' ORDER BY count desc limit 1";
echo 'pre: ';
$result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
foreach($result as $row)
{
echo $row['prerender'];
}
```

UPDATE: now it works

Comment: You need {} around your variables like $canonical="https://{$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]}{$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]}"

Comment: Also, echo $canonical, make sure it is right and if you can, use phpMyadmin to check the db contains what you think it does. I'm also not sure you should use IGNORE if you're doing ON DUPLICATE KEY - might want to research that

Comment: oh and quotes around HTTP_HOST and REQUEST_URI

Comment: Thank you, actually the data are inserted into db, also in this way. Also, into the db there is the data I want. So the first part is working. I just can't echo it, i get bool(false)

Comment: if you know the data is in the db, the final step is just echo $sql2 before you use it and paste it here

Comment: echo $sql2 print the query not the result :(

Comment: `$sql2 = "SELECT prerender FROM `PRERENDER` WHERE `canonical` = '$canonical' ORDER BY count desc limit 1";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
var_dump($results);`

Comment: echo sql2 itself and paste it here - the actual query being used, i.e. "SELECT..."

Comment: SELECT prerender FROM `PRERENDER` WHERE `canonical` = `http://apps.evemilano.com/` ORDER BY count desc limit 1

Comment: well the canonical needs quotes around it (plus it doesn't have the /1 so it won't match anything?)

Comment: I get this result, you know what does it means? object(mysqli_result)#2974 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: solved! I update the code thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `prerender` FROM `PRERENDER` WHERE (`canonical` = '.$canonical.')
ORDER BY `count` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT prerender 
FROM PRERENDER 
WHERE canonical = $canonical
ORDER BY count desc
limit 1
```

Comment: thank you, how can I echo the prerender field value?

I try:
     echo mysql_result($sql2, 0); //blank page

or 

     echo mysql_query($sql2);  //again blank page

Comment: You should really take a PHP tutuorial. And don't use `mysql_query`. It was deprecated like decades ago. Use PDO or MYSQLi.

Comment: thank you, I'm a beginner :( I use $results = mysqli_query($sql2);
var_dump($results); but the result is NULL